# Simple textfield validator using Reactive Cocoa

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

I am testing ReactiveCocoa in a playground. I would like to test for the validity of a string before performing a network request.

I am not sure how to combine the textfield signal and the validation signal tho. The part of the code that is marked [??] => what is the right way to do that filter?

```
var textField = UITextField()

textField.text = "http://localhost:3000/users.json"

let searchStringsProducer = textField.rac_textSignal().toSignalProducer()

let searchStringValidProducer = searchStringsSignal.toSignalProducer().map{
  text in
  (text as! String).containsString("http")
}

// this produces a ReactiveCocoa.SignalProducer<(Optional<AnyObject>, Bool), NSError>. 
let searchStringCombined = combineLatest(searchStringsProducer, searchStringValidProducer)


// turns the simple search results into a signal 
let searchResults = searchStringCombined

// [??] i would like to ONLY execute on the rest of the actions if it is valid
.map{ // what do i do here before passing on to the network API }

.flatMap(FlattenStrategy.Latest) { 
  latestStr -> SignalProducer<[AnyObject], NSError> in
    return requestJSON(latestStr, parameters: nil)
    .flatMapError { error in
      print("Network error occurred: \(error)")
      return SignalProducer.empty
    }

}.observeOn(uis)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let searchStringValidProducer = searchStringsSignal.toSignalProducer().map { text in
  (text as! String).containsString("http")
}

let searchStringCombined = combineLatest(searchStringsProducer, searchStringValidProducer)
```

This pattern is troubling, because when `searchStringsProducer` sends a value, `searchStringCombined` will send *two* values -- one for the new string, and one for the new boolean. It would be neater to define this signal like this:

```
let searchStringCombined = searchStringsSignal.toSignalProducer().map { text in
  (text, (text as! String).containsString("http"))
}
```

Which gives you the same result.

---

But you don't need to define `searchStringCombined` at all, unless you're using it elsewhere. You should be able to get by with a simple `filter`:

```
searchStringsSignal.toSignalProducer().filter({ text in
  (text as! String).containsString("http")
}).map({
    /* whatever goes here */
}).flatMap(FlattenStrategy.Latest) {
    /* perform network request */
}
```

`filter` is kind of like `map`, in that it takes a function and returns a signal. But it only lets some values through, allowing you to only make network requests based on the valid inputs.

Comment: ian, thanks for the great explanation. works great. what i am still a little confused by is the fact how i can combine 2 signalproducers of different types and combine them into one stream.

Comment: On another note, RxSwift appears to do strict generic typing of observables more elegantly.

Comment: @mingyeow You can get that with `flatten(.Merge)`. It's nice as a helper: `func merge<T, E>(signals: SignalProducer<T, E>...) -> SignalProducer<T, E> { return SignalProducer(values: signals).flatten(.Merge) }`. RAC 4 has nice generically typed signals, but the UIKit extensions are all inherited from the untyped RAC 2 helpers...

Comment: (Of course, you need to map them into the same type first... like a signal of enums that cover the two cases, for example.)